# View section of the site takes too time to load

Tags: php, javascript, performance, smarty

I am developing a web site using PHP,Smarty and MySQL. It takes a long time to load the view part of the web site . I can get and see the data from the database quickly, problem is with the display section.

```
http://jobsgang.com/c0b0dfc2379f0379d546b727/Kerala_jobs/Kozhikode_jobs/Other_Places_in_Kozhikode_jobs/Engineering_Projects_jobs/Engineer_jobs/btech_be_jobs/experienced_jobs/permanent_jobs/We_are_looking_for_Fresh_Talented__Project_Management_Tranies.html
```

You can see the data from the php out here . It will load quickly, but the display section of the site will take long time .

Please help me to solve it

Comment: I think there is no problem with the length of the url. It is not the problem. You can see the php out put there .

Comment: Have you tried profiling with Xdebug etc?

Comment: Please post the code you use to render your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP , You have some Crazy ajax call on that page like every second calling a page that does not exist.

[image]

Remove the following  script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-506aa6a401ec5bef"></script>
```

Comment: Dear Baba,Thanks for your valuable suggestion. How can I find out that crazy ajax call ? Please replay

Comment: I have a code in my htacess as ErrorDocument 404 http://jobsgang.com/404.php. Is this cause that problem ?

Comment: No that is not the problem .. your script is trying to call a page that does not exist so its aromatically redirect to `jobsgang.com/404.php`

Comment: Dear Baba, Thanks I removed ErrorDocument 404 http://jobsgang.com/404.php from htacess file and now it is working fine . Thanks for your valuable suggestion. But I would like to include 404 redirect in htacess. How can I include that.

Comment: I did not ask you to remove `ErrorDocument 404 jobsgang.com/404.php` i  asked you to remove the java script that is calling a page that does not exist

Comment: But baba how can I find out thet particular call from the script. Please help me

Comment: Look at my answer again .. already given you a script to remove

Comment: I have remove the script {literal}<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-506aa6a401ec5bef"></script>{/literal} but now I can see the out put but the page continuously loading.....

Answer (score 1):

This is the result from chrome and also the suggestions from it,

```
**Combine external JavaScript (6)**
There are multiple resources served from same domain. Consider combining them into as  
few files as possible.
6 JavaScript resources served from epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg.

**Enable gzip compression (13)**
Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by about    
two thirds (~638.28KB):
css could save ~188B
container.html could save ~4.37KB
container.css could save ~23.98KB
jquery.js could save ~66.14KB
jsonStringify.js could save ~3.96KB
jquery-ui.custom.js could save ~304.30KB
jquery.additions.js could save ~2.05KB
jquery.batchImageLoad.js could save ~1.44KB
container.js could save ~196.65KB
chrome-extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/initData.json could save ~1.29KB
xd_arbiter.php could save ~16.80KB
xd_arbiter.php could save ~16.80KB
about.css could save ~305B

**Leverage browser caching (18)**
The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if    
possible:
We_are_looking_for_Fresh_Talented__Project_Management_Tranies.html
container.html
container.css
jquery.js
jsonStringify.js
jquery-ui.custom.js
jquery.additions.js
jquery.batchImageLoad.js
container.js
chrome-extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/initData.json
endSeperator.gif
expend.png
arrow_down.png
addApp.png
seperator.png
xd_arbiter.php
xd_arbiter.php
about.css

**Leverage proxy caching (5)**
The following publicly cacheable resources contain a Set-Cookie header. This security   
vulnerability can cause cookies to be shared by multiple users.
style.css
pagination.css
jquery-1.4.2.min.js
ajaxSignUp.js
all.js

**Minimize cookie size**
The average cookie size for all requests on this page is 27B

**Specify image dimensions (1)**
A width and height should be specified for all images in order to speed up page   
display. The following image(s) are missing a width and/or height:
lock.png (5 uses)
Web Page Performance
**Optimize the order of styles and scripts (4)**
The following external CSS files were included after an external JavaScript file in the   
document head. To ensure CSS files are downloaded in parallel, always include external   
CSS before external JavaScript.
about.css
3 inline script blocks were found in the head between an external CSS file and another   
resource. To allow parallel downloading, move the inline script before the external CSS   
file, or after the next resource.

**Remove unused CSS rules (510)**
78.97KB (88%) of CSS is not used by the current page.
style.css: 17.28KB (78%) is not used by the current page.
pagination.css: 692B (76%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #1: 3.63KB (88%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #2: 11.95KB (85%) is not used by the current page.
about.css: 447B (100%) is not used by the current page.
container.css: 31.69KB (92%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #3: 28B (11%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #4: 13.28KB (98%) is not used by the current page.

**Use normal CSS property names instead of vendor-prefixed ones (6)**
We_are_looking_for_Fresh_Talented__Project_Management_Tranies.html
about.css
data:text/html,chro…
__________________________  chrome-   
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12120
|         02:05:57         | chrome-
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12121
Init chrome extension communication chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12124
__________________________  chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12120
|         02:05:57         | chrome-
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12121
Init chrome extension communication chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12124
__________________________  container.js:569
|         02:05:59         | container.js:570
Init chrome extension communication container.js:573
__________________________  container.js:569
|         02:05:59         | container.js:570 
Initializing main toolbar container container.js:573
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). all.js:54
__________________________  chrome-   
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12120
|         02:06:00         | chrome-   
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12121
Init chrome extension communication chrome-   
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12124
__________________________  chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12120
|         02:06:00         | chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12121
Init chrome extension communication chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12124
__________________________  chrome- 
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12120
|         02:06:00         | chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12121
Init chrome extension communication chrome-
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12124
__________________________  chrome-
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12120
|         02:06:00         | chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12121
Init chrome extension communication chrome-  
extension://epbkomalpdcfielganbfombgchcdebfg/js/contentScript.js:12124
```

And look the texts in red color,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the view part that takes so long to render you should debug that:

If you're using Smarty and have many templates to be rendered – that could be a reason. Try to turn on caching in smarty.

Also turn on the smarty debug console and check if rendereing takes a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

this is ur root problem all.js is on the fritz